# createFromObjects() not working in phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I' am trying to make a game in phaser. I have created a tilemap, with an objectlayer. However when I' am trying to add an object from the object layer to the group "checkers" the overlap doesn't work. 
Here is my code:

```
function preload()
{
    game.load.spritesheet("bird","assets/flappybird.png",92,64,3);
    game.load.tilemap('map', 'assets/map.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
    game.load.image('tiles', 'assets/obstacle.png');
    game.load.image('checktiles', 'assets/empty.png');
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#c9c9c9';

}
function create()
{
     game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
     map = game.add.tilemap('map');
     //OBSTACLES
     map.addTilesetImage('obstacle', 'tiles');
     layer = map.createLayer('Tilelaag 1');
     layer.resizeWorld();
     map.setCollisionBetween(1, 12);
     //CHECKERS
     checkers = game.add.group();
     checkers.enableBody=true;
     map.createFromObjects('Object Checkers', 5, 'checktiles', 0, true, false, checkers);
    //PLAYER
    player=game.add.sprite(92,game.world.heigth-300,"bird");
    player.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
    game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
    player.body.gravity.y=300;
    player.animations.add("fly",[0,1,2],10,true);
    player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    player.body.velocity.x=150;
    //CURSORS
    cursors=game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    spacebar=game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
    //CAMERA
    game.camera.follow(player);
}
function update()
{
    var hit=game.physics.arcade.collide(layer,player);
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, checkers,Addpoint,null,this);
    player.animations.play("fly");
    if(spacebar.isDown)
    {
        player.body.velocity.y = -150;
    }
    if(hit)
    {
        game.state.restart();
    }
}
function Addpoint()
{
    console.log("Called");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose somewhere in your JSON file right after the layer data should have something like this:

```
...
{
         "draworder":"topdown",
         "height":0,
         "name":"Object Checkers",
         "objects":[
                {
                 //First object
                 "height":43.5,
                 "id":2,
                 "name":"",
                 "rotation":0,
                 "type":"",
                 "visible":true,
                 "width":43.5,
                 "x":158.25,
                 "y":178,
                 "gid":5
                }, 
                {
                 //Second object
                 "height":43.5,
                 "id":9,
                 "name":"",
                 "rotation":0,
                 "type":"",
                 "visible":true,
                 "width":43.5,
                 "x":117.5,
                 "y":257.75,
                 "gid":5
                }, 
                {
                 //Third object (if it exists), etc...
                 ...
```

The id, rotation, name, width, length and other attributes can vary of course but the GID does not. You need the GID attribute on each element of the array (in this case it is 5), you can place it manually in each object.

After verifying this, what it would do would be:

```
var map, layer, checkers;

function create()
{
     game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
     //Map
     map = game.add.tilemap('map');
     //I understand that here is the name of the tileset as specified in the map data.
     map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
     layer = map.createLayer('Tilelaag 1');
     layer.resizeWorld();
     map.setCollisionBetween(1, 12);
     //Checkers
     checkers = game.add.group();
     checkers.enableBody = true;
     /*
        First parameter: string of map objects layer.
        Second parameter: Gid.
        Third parameter: sprite string to use.
        Fourth parameter: value of the frame to initialize the object.
        Fifth parameter: default status of the sprite.
        Sixth parameter: autocull. The sprites that are autoculled are culled from the camera if out of its range..
        Seventh parameter: the group is specified
     */
     map.createFromObjects('Object Checkers', 5, 'checktiles', 0, true, false, checkers);
     console.log(checkers.length);
    //create player, controls, etc...
    ...
}
```

It is possible that the position of the objects is affected, you can use:

```
map.createFromObjects('Object Checkers', 5, 'checktiles', 0, true, false, checkers, Phaser.Sprite, false);
```

An [example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/create-from-objects)